# Proper size calculation of grid tooltip

Tags: user-interface, apl, dyalog

Using Dyalog APL I'm trying to create a grid with cell tooltips. These tooltips are created with the method *AddComment*. For some reason the tooltip does not resize itself to fit the content so if the text doesn't fit it will be cut off. Therefor a size calculation is required before the tooltip is created. The method *GetTextSize* can be used to retrieve the size of a text in pixels for the used font. However, this method seems to report the wrong size despite setting the *Coord* property to 'Pixel'.

Here is an example which illustrates the problem:

```
 ∇ ShowGrid;col;comment;height;row;width
   'F'⎕WC'Form'
   'F.G'⎕WC'Grid'(2 2⍴0)(0 0)(100 100)
   comment←↑'line one' 'line two' 'line three'
   row col←1 2
   'F.G' ⎕WS'Coord' 'Pixel'
   height width←4+F.G.GetTextSize comment
   F.G.AddComment row col comment height width
 ∇
```

I also add four pixels to the reported size of the text since the border and padding of the tooltip seems to be one pixel each. The window created with this function is shown in the image below. Only the text "line one" is visible in the tooltip. I also tried setting *Coord* to 'RealPixel' and 'ScaledPixel' respectively but it made no difference. My question is basically: What is the proper way to calculate the tooltip size so that any given text will be displayed in its entirety? I'm using Dyalog APL 16.0 Classic.

[image: Grid with cell tooltip]

Comment: I've forwarded this question to Dyalog support a response may be delayed due to holidays. Please be patient, and we will get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

The comment is drawn with a font that is different to the one used by `F.G.GetTextSize`. Unfortunately there is currently no simple way to retrieve the size of the font that is actually used.

We will look into ways to fix this.

Comment: Note that [John Daintree](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/John_Daintree) is the author of Dyalog APL's `⎕WC` graphics system function.

Comment: Aha, I didn't notice (or expected) a different font for the comment.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Maybe it is possible to determine which font and size is being used, and then compute the size based on that?

Answer (score 1):

OK, try this one for 32 bit CLASSIC. The difference is in the SIZE of the structure (504 bytes for a Unicode interpreter, 344 for classic). This is because the font names use 2 byte characters in Unicode and 1 byte characters in classic.

```
 ⎕IO ⎕ML←1 0
 FNT←' I4 I4 I4 I4 I4 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 T[32] '                ⍝ A LOGFONT structure
 NCM←'{U4 I4 I4 I4 I4 I4 ',FNT,'I4 I4',FNT,'I4 I4',FNT,FNT,FNT,'I4}' ⍝ A NONCLIENTMETRICSW structure
 SIZE←344                                                            ⍝ The size of the above
 ⎕NA'DYALOG32|MEMCPY >',NCM,' <U1[] U'                               ⍝ Useful copy with format
 ⎕NA'U user32|SystemParametersInfo* U U =U1[',(⍕SIZE),'] U '         ⍝ Get the data as an array of bytes
 r←SystemParametersInfo 41 0(SIZE↑88 1)0
 f←MEMCPY(83⍴0)(2⊃r)SIZE                                             ⍝ And copy to a NCM structure
 tip←f[53 66]                                                        ⍝ And extract the relevant bits
 (2⊃tip)~←⎕UCS 0                                                     ⍝ and remove trailing nulls from name
```

Comment: Thanks! This version doesn't crash but it returns a two-element vector where the first element is -12 and the second 'Segoe UI'. What is the interpretation of -12?

Comment: I found some information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfonta. If the value is negative, the absolute value is the font size (excluding the leading) in logical units. Could it be that the font size is 12 pixels and the leading 3 pixels, which adds up to a line height of 15 pixels as in my example solution with the tooltip font hard coded?

Comment: Or is abs(-12) * 96 / 72 = 16 the right calculation given 96 DPI and 72 PPI?

Comment: If I use 'Segoe UI' 16 instead of 'Segoe UI' 15 in my solution with a hard coded font I get the same (correct) box size.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround suggested by Adám is to determine and hard code the font used for comments and then use *GetTextSize* with this font as a parameter. With some guess work and testing I found it to be "Segoe UI" of size 15 pixels. Below is a (rather fragile) solution. It's fragile in the sense that it only works correctly if the user hasn't changed the default font or font size.

```
∇ ShowGrid;border;col;comment;boxSize;commentSize;padding;row
  'F'⎕WC'Form'
  'F.G'⎕WC'Grid'(2 2⍴0)(0 0)(100 100)
  comment←↑'line one' 'line two' 'line three'
  row col←1 2
  'F.G'⎕WS'Coord' 'Pixel'
  'F.G.FNT'⎕WC'Font' 'Segoe UI' 15
  commentSize←F.G.GetTextSize comment'#.F.G.FNT'
  (border padding)←1
  boxSize←commentSize+2×border+padding
  F.G.AddComment row col comment,boxSize
∇
```

[image: comment tooltip with all text visible]

Answer (score 0):

The following is an APL/⎕NA translation of how the interpreter gets thr information about the tip font from the operating system.

```
∇ tip←tip_font;FNT;NCM;SIZE;⎕IO;⎕ML;SystemParametersInfo;MEMCPY;tip;r;GetLastError;f
 ⎕IO ⎕ML←1 0
 FNT←' I4 I4 I4 I4 I4 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 U1 T[32] '                ⍝ A LOGFONT structure
 NCM←'{U4 I4 I4 I4 I4 I4 ',FNT,'I4 I4',FNT,'I4 I4',FNT,FNT,FNT,'I4}' ⍝ A NONCLIENTMETRICSW structure
 SIZE←504                                                            ⍝ The size of the above
 ⎕NA'DYALOG64|MEMCPY >',NCM,' <U1[] U'                               ⍝ Useful copy with format
 ⎕NA'U user32|SystemParametersInfo* U U =U1[',(⍕SIZE),'] U '         ⍝ Get the data as an array of bytes
 r←SystemParametersInfo 41 0(SIZE↑248 1)0
 f←MEMCPY(83⍴0)(2⊃r)SIZE                                             ⍝ And copy to a NCM structure
 tip←f[53 66]                                                        ⍝ And extract the relevant bits
 (2⊃tip)~←⎕UCS 0                                                     ⍝ and remove trailing nulls from name
∇
```

Comment: I get an error on line 5: "FILE ERROR 2 No such file or directory: Shared library could not be loaded."

Comment: Is there a 32-bit version? I tried to replace DYALOG64 with DYALOG32 but then the session was aborted.

Comment: Just changing DYALOG64 to DYALOG32 worked fine for me (with Dyalog 18.2). What version of the interpreter are you using?

Comment: I use Dyalog APL 16.0 Classic.

Comment: Ah, OK. The CLASSIC make a difference. I'll work on an updated sample.